# How to get unique properties in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, distinct

I have a collection in Mongo, where are records similar to this:

```
{ "id": NumberLong(141242), "name": "John Doe", "language": "en" }
{ "id": NumberLong(3556332), "name": "Mark Zuckerberg", "language": "jp" }
{ "id": NumberLong(124), "name": "Abigail Fidler", "language": "cn" }
{ "id": NumberLong(325262351), "name": "Joe Parker", "language": "jp" }
{ "id": NumberLong(98798), "name": "John Bush", "language": "en" }
```

and i would like to select all unique languages from that collection.

```
{ "language": "en" }
{ "language": "jp" }
{ "language": "cn" }
```

Is there any way how to do it in Mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB has a [distinct](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct) command for this.

Example from the `mongo` shell:

```
> db.mydb.distinct("language");
[ "en", "jp", "cn" ]
```